# The difference between "I can't agree with it enough" and "I can't entirely agree with it enough"

Tags: meaning

I know what "I can't agree with it enough" means, but I wonder how it will be if 'entirely' is added? I once heard someone telling me 'entirely' shoulde be erased because the 'entirely' have the conflicting meaning with 'enough' only in this sentence. I wonder the difference in meaning.

Comment: Why do you want to add "entirely"? You can't put words in a sentence for no reason..

Comment: It's not really idiomatic to say [*I can't agree with it enough*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+can%27t+agree+with+it+enough%22). People certainly do say *I can't agree enough* (without *with it*), but we're *much* more likely to say [***I couldn't agree more***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+can%27t+agree+enough%2CI+couldn%27t+agree+more&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20could%20not%20agree%20more%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's idiomatic to my Canadian ears, though it's more likely phrased with the speaker, rather than the idea as the object, "*I can't agree with **you** enough*".

Answer (score 5):

If you know what "I can't agree with it enough" means, then you would know that "I can't entirely agree with it enough" is contradicting in nature.

Recall that the idiom, "I can't agree with it enough", suggests that you completely agree.

If you say, "I can't entirely agree", you are suggesting that you don't fully agree.

Hence, "I can't entirely agree with it enough" makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Actually here there's no serious difference between this two options